# Правильно ли то что я добавляю unsigned типы в Java-проекте?

Tags: java, reverse-engineering

Решил написать свои собственные типы по работе с безннаковыми типами и операциями с ними. Это вызвано тем что достаточно часто пишу тулзы по работе с исполняемыми файлами формата PE и то мне не хватает поддержки беззнаковых типов в Java. Мне нужны типы аналогичные С-шным uint32_t, uint64_t, uint16_t, uint8_t, которые расположены в стандартном хидере cstdint соглассно стандарту C++11.

Да, я конечно наслышан, что подобное уже написали в Grovy. Однако при работе с коллегой по работе услышал мнение "Раз тебе в Java понадобилось работать так низкоуровнево, значит ты что-то не так делаешь. Возможно тебе лучше отказаться от юзания Java в подобных проектах, она не для этого предназначена".

После того как услышал это мнение я полез "гуглить" и нашел мнение автора Java о том почему же он не добавил изначально подобное в язык. Также натолкнулся на несколько тем с обсуждением беззнаковых типов в Java на stackoverflow.com.

Вопрос сего поста: Приходилось ли Вам добавлять подобное в свои проекты и не жалели ли Вы об этом в последствии?

Меня интересует прежде всего Практическая сторона дела, а не теоретические возгласы. Буду рад услышать мнение ребят из мира reversing-engineeringa, а еще лучше тех кто писал крипторы или их анализ\взлом и др. около-кулхацкерные проекты

Answer (score 1):

Не приходилось. Обычно вместо беззнаковых можно использовать знаковые, достаточно следить за некоторыми моментами:

- нежелательное размножение знакового бита при приведении к большему формату
- написать свои процедуры сравнения, трактующие числа как беззнаковые

Вообще целое - это набор битов, а знаковое оно или нет - определяется операцией. Вам достаточно определить свои операции (в виде процедур), а пользовательский тип в Яве предполагает хранение в куче, что накладно.

То есть это похоже на то, как программируют на ассемблере - при объявлении переменной указывают размер, но не указывают знаковость, а для знаковых и беззнаковых значений используют знаковые или беззнаковые операции.

Другой прием - при считывании из файла преобразовывать к бОльшему формату (uint32->long), тогда можно использовать стандартные операции. При записи в файл просто обрезают до нужного размера.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше внимание! Меня как раз и беспокоит возможность забыть и не учесть где-либо этот знаковый бит! ;) Буквально недавно выявил багу с помощью юнит-теста, но до написания которого догадался только спустя 3-4 дня. 

Тревожит следующее. В С-стиле я привык писать:

   uint32_t executableDecryptionKey = extractKeyFromPolymorphicCode();

uint32_t extractKeyFromPolymorphicCode() {
//more code
  return *(*uint32_t)(&entryPoint[pseudoEip]);
}

На Java так не получится. Надо будет:
1) Читать явно 4 байта
2) Явно их присваивать какому либо объекту псевдо-uint32-t типа

//end-of-part-one

Comment: Но это если простая задача. А что если я работаю с последовательностью dword-ов, каждый из которых нужно проанализировать на предмет возможного виртуального адреса?

Мне хочется избежать прежде всего overhead-а и но я не знаю как на практике ведет себя код на Java работающий с байтам на столь низком уровне

//end-of-my-commentary

Answer (score 0):

Многократно приходилось переписывать сишные прожекты с использованием `unsigned` на Java, но всегда как-то обходилось без введения специального `unsigned` типа. На худой конец всегда можно обратиться к типу `BigInteger` - длина практически ничем не ограничена - бери да пользуйся.

Comment: У Вас наверное сохранился хоть один из подобных проектов. Можете привести куски кода? Мне также важна и читаемость кода. Ну или ссылку на гитхаб\битбакет